# Using App Engine with a custom domain, without paying for Google Apps?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-apps

Can you use Google App Engine with your own custom domain, without paying for the whole Google Apps business package?

The [setup instructions](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/domain) suggests this is not possible. Has anyone found a work around?

Comment: Note: App Engine previously offered a "free single user edition of Google Apps Standard for free - for the purpose of managing custom domains", but this offer was withdrawn in December 2012.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You no longer need google apps for using custom domain with GAE. you can use custom domains without signing up for Google Apps for Business.

1. go to https://console.developers.google.com and click on your
2. project and select appengine then click on settings
3. there you can add and verify your domain using Google Webmaster central

Once you're done verifying you're all set to go !

Comment: That worked for me. Seems you still need to use a Google Apps domain if you need SSL support, but this is quite useful in the meantime.

Comment: Doesn't appear to work any longer, I was only able to setup a 'naked domain' (example.com), the button to add a subdomain (www.example.com) remained disabled.

Answer (score 8):

IF one has had a free Google Apps account prior to the December 2012 deadline, there does seem to be an easy solution to mapping a new GAE app to a newly registered domain. I happen to still have such prior account for which I do not have to pay (yet?), I believe. I suspect other long-term GAE developers are in a similar situations. So, I am adding quick instructions I found and translated [from here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-appengine/CMrtWvwpV6U/ejLNKGDJT3EJ). (There are many related threads on the topic on stackoverflow. This question seems the most relevant for adding these notes.)

1. Login to your existing Google Apps account
2. Go to "Domains" and hit "add a domain or a domain alias"
3. Keep "Add a domain alias of ..." selected and enter the new domain name in the field
4. Go through the required domain verification process
5. Now back on the main admin screen, hit "Google Apps" and click "add Services" (a box icon on the top right)
6. Under "Other Services" enter your GAE app ID
7. On the "Settings for " page coming up, hit "Add new URL"
8. Select the domain name added in Step 1+, adding a prefix such as "www" in front
9. Confirm and be done with it

Just done and verified. Works for me and I suspect the same procedure would work for any further domains the same way.

DISCLAIMER: Again, this is for people with a prior Google Apps account. However, it should also be relevant for people that paid for a single such account. This single account should then be sufficient to map multiple GAE apps to multiple domains, if you don't need an independent copy of the other Google apps goodies every time.

Comment: As a further note, there is some official documentation related to the above: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/domain. Regrettably, from that posting, I failed to understand that you just need one Google apps account overall and you can do the entire domain configuration without doing anything on the GAE settings side. And given all the requests for help I've been digging through, I suspect I am not the only one.

Comment: That appears to be the only option currently working.

Answer (score 5):

Starting June 15 and for a limited time, Google will offer a USD $50.00 App Engine credit for Google App Engine developers who have recently purchased a new Google Apps for Business domain account for their App Engine application.

To review the terms and conditions for this site and request a credit for an eligible application, please visit [this site](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1lSDA5Jol0Bosaop3RKZ9YqlSyzVLsCtAv8gYupBheR4/viewform).

Here is the google groups discussion : https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/google-appengine/jC_K-YlmXhM

Quoting from the link above:

> We are working on a solution that will make this process simpler for
>   developers and not require a paid subscription for Google Apps for
>   Business.
>
> In the meantime, starting from June 15, we will offer a $50 App Engine
>   credit for developers who need to purchase a new Google Apps for
>   Business domain in order to associate a domain with an App Engine
>   account.

Comment: Thank you. I was hoping for a technical solution (e.g. some type of DNS forwarding independent of Google), but it looks like I may have to wait.

Answer (score 2):

Actually there is one free solution, for people that don't have Google Apps account yet.

1. Go to AppEngine -> Application Settings -> Add domain -> Sign up for Google Apps
2. Start a free 30 day trial - Do not add the billing options
3. Setup your domain
4. Add the domain to your app engine project
5. When the 30 day trial expire the domain will still work.

Comment: But without SSL support?

Comment: That worked, but then you are not able to use the email, which was important for me. Luckily I had a ancient google apps account that I could use to create an Alias.

Comment: If you want to use the email, you have to pay.